# Windows 7 only sees empty directories

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a new computer with Windows 7 installed.
My old computer had Windows Vista installed.

I took the old internal drive from the old computer and have plugged it into the new computer using a Sata->USB adapter.

I've launched a cmd.exe window and an explorer shell both with "Administrator" priviledge.

However, many of the directories are empty.

The few files that *do* show up, I cannot read:

```
E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>date
The current date is: 14/05/2012
Enter the new date: (dd-mm-yy)
E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>dir
 Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CCC7-D79E

 Directory of E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0

30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          .
30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          ..
30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          AddIns
30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          bin
30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          data
30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          doc
28/08/2010  21:25                65 SharpDevelop.url
           1 File(s)             65 bytes
           6 Dir(s)  131,958,325,248 bytes free

E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>type SharpDevelop.url
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>dir bin
 Volume in drive E has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CCC7-D79E

 Directory of E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0

30/11/2010  21:27    <DIR>          bin
           0 File(s)              0 bytes
           1 Dir(s)  131,958,325,248 bytes free

E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>dir bin\bin
The system cannot find the file specified.

E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>cd bin
The system cannot find the path specified.

E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0>
```

The above is just an example of the many files and directories that I cannot access from the old drive.

What's going on?

Is the drive corrupted? Or is it something to do with Windows 7 reading Vista drives?

If it's corrupted, I can I confirm this?

How can I get access to all of the data?

(P.S. I don't have a Linux or Mac box).

Comment: In reply to your P.S., you could also try a [LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD)

Answer (score 1):

You need to claim ownership of the files/folders on the drive.

1. Right click on the drive, Properties.
2. Security
3. Advanced
4. Owner tab
5. Edit
6. Other Users or groups
7. advanced
8. Find now
9. "everyone"
10. ok
11. ok
12. Check "Replace owner on sub-containers and objects"
13. Ok

It should then start to give your current administrator on the new computer permissions to access the folders and all the files in those folders all the way down (hopefully)

Depending on the amount of data, this could take quite a while, and there are some prompts you may have to be around to answer and keep the process moving.

Good luck!

Comment: "Error Applying Security"

Comment: An error occurred while applying security information to: "E:\Program Files\SharpDevelop\3.0\AddIns"

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Got that in a message box when I tried to follow your steps just for the "SharpDevelop" folder

Comment: Was the drive protected by Bitlocker?  

Are you able to run a chkdsk /r on the drive?

Comment: "E:\>chkdsk/r
The type of the file system is RAW.
Cannot lock current drive.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives."

Comment: Aww, that sounds like fun.  Thar be the root of our problem.  Its possible the boot sector got corrupted on the IDE drive.  You may have luck with the instructions listed here (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/win7-sees-partition-as-raw-file-system/fd7549b2-7021-4bfe-9bcf-50d5c09f0a72)